# WCF was unable to deserialize List with in a Dictionary element

Tags: c#, wcf

```
[DataContract]
    public class AssetData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<AssetData> ChildAssets { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public AssetData ParentNode { get; set; }
    }

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string, AssetData>))]
    public interface IRtxEquipmentConfiguration
    {
        [OperationContract] 
        object GetData(string sKey, string sRequest);
    }
```

For the above OperationContract `"GetData"` the server is returning a Dictionary of AssetData.
I have marked AssetData as a DataContract and all its fields as DataMembers.
At the client side, I was getting wcf error "The socket connection has been disposed.\r\nObject name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection'.". I suspected this error is because of the field ChildAssets.
When I disable this field alone (By removing DataMember tag), then at the client side, I was able to get all the Dictionary elements and with in each element all the fields except ChildAssets.
I am able to see remaining fields Name, ParentNode and Priority.

Any clue why WCF fails to serialize a List with in a Dictionary element?

Comment: What client are you using? Maybe the the webservice reference on the client wants an ObservableCollection instead of a List

Comment: Rumplin, Right now both Client and Server are in the same process. I am using .NET 4.0 framework and C# language. It is a self hosted service and at the client side (which is just another dll in my case in the same process) I am casting the object to Dictionary<string, AssetData>. Everything is fine, except only the DataMember ChildAssets

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, change the List<AssetData> to ObservableCollection<AssetData>

Comment: Is it possible that when you include the child assets you are reaching the limits defined on the binding?  I.e. a Depth limit, max buffer size, etc?  To test, re-include `ChildAssets` and force the method to only return a dictionary with a single keyvaluepair, containing an AssetData that has only a single child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding `IsReference = true` to my DataContract class AssetData. The object graph has references to other instances of AssetData class. ChildAssets members are just references to other instances of AssetData.